# selecting td first child from tr is not getting

Tags: javascript

```js
  $(function () {
            $("tr").click(function () {

                $(this).addClass("selected");
            });

            //************** for left working***************//
            $("button").click(function () {

                var CurrentTrId = $("tr.selected").attr("data-id");

                var ParrentTrId = (CurrentTrId) - 1;

                if (ParrentTrId == 0) {
                    return
                }

                var CurrentTrLeftValue = parseInt($(".selected > td:first-child ").css("padding-left"));
                console.log(CurrentTrLeftValue);
                var ParrentTrLeftValue = parseInt($("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "']td:first-child").css("padding-left"));
                if (NewCurrentTrLeftValue == ParrentTrLeftValue) {

                    if (CurrentTrLeftValue <= 40) {

                        CurrentTrLeftValue = (CurrentTrLeftValue + 20);


                        $(".selected > td:first-child").css({ "padding-left": CurrentTrLeftValue });
                        $(".selected > td:first-child").addClass("normal");
                        $('#', ParrentTrId).addClass('bold');
                    }
                }       });

        })
```

```css
 .table {
    position:static;
      width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse;
        
       
}
            .table td {
                border: 1px solid;
                border-color: lightgray;
               
                height: 17px;
            }
            .selected{
                 background-color:lightskyblue;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
        <tr>
        <td>hi</td> <td>hi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>me</td> <td>me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>you</td> <td>you</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button>clickme</button>
```

i want select td:first child from my tr i use this code

```js
  var LeftValue = parseInt($("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").css("padding-left"));
```

but its not taken is there any method for this? 
the "parrentid is a variable which store the parrent data-id"

i have a table and a button i want move my selectable tr content into 20 px left on click the button first time. on second click i want move it 20px again(total40px). i write some code here

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet...?

Comment: hi i add the complete code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:first-child` to select the first child

```
var LeftValue = $("tr[data-id='1'] td:first-child").text();
alert(LeftValue)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/tyqv8pbx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this selector returns data

```
$("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child");
```

If not then use this

```
$("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] td:first-child");
```

And then make sure that

`parseInt($("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").css("padding-left"));`  doesnt return string like '123px'

Answer (score -1):

Usually the error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" occurs when Jquery library has not been included in the HTML page.
You can use the following code to include the Jquery file and then try :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```